# complex requirements for Data wrangling using python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

This is my original text field

```
Area    Brand   Points
USA     Nike    86
USA     Addidas 85
USA     Speedo  84
USA     Nike    83
USA     Speedo  82
USA     Nike    81
Japan   Nike    84
Japan   Nike    85
Japan   Nike    86
Japan   Addidas 82
Japan   Addidas 80
Japan   Addidas 86
Japan   Speedo  84
Japan   Speedo  82
```

For the Area column, it only show the unique value
For the Brand column, it will show the high frequency value
For the Points column, it only show the mean() results

So, it should be same as the below.

```
Area    | ModBrand        | AvePoints
USA     | NIKE            | MEAN NUMBER
Japan   | [NIKE, Addidas] | MEAN NUMBER
```

I know I can use the groupby function for the Area and mean for Points

```
data = data.groupby(['Area']).mean().reset_index()
```

But for the Brand column. May you give me some tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) like so:

```
df.groupby('Area').agg({'Brand': lambda x: x.mode().values.tolist(), 'Points': 'mean'})
```

Gives:

```
                 Brand  Points
Area                          
Japan  [Addidas, Nike]  83.625
USA             [Nike]  83.500
```